# Es posible guardar varios datos que se solicitan con prompt(), que no sea guardandolos en un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, array, prompt

No se me ocurre otra forma, pero quería ver si hay alguna alternativa para guardar muchos datos que necesitan ser solicitados al usuario que no sea la de guardarlos en un vector. Hablo dentro de Javascript claro.

```
 <script>
    let num1 = prompt("Ingrese un numero entero");
    let num2 = prompt("Ingrese un numero entero");
    let num3 = prompt("Ingrese un numero entero");
    let num4 = prompt("Ingrese un numero entero");
    let num5 = prompt("Ingrese un numero entero");
    let num6 = prompt("Ingrese un numero entero");

    let operacion = (num1 + num2 + num3) + ((num3 * num4 * num5) + num6);

    console.log(operacion);
</script>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. En cuanto a tu pregunta, las posibles respuestas pueden ser: ¿En un objeto tal vez? ¿En un Set? ¿En `n` variables?. ¿Cuál sería el problema específico que tienes? Tal como está tu pregunta es difícil responder y parece basarse en opiniones. Saludos

Comment: Y entonces donde lo quieres guardar ?

Comment: Claro osea, lo ideal seria en n variables, en cuanto a objetos seguro se puede pero como todavia no llegue a esa parte lo evito, a los arreglos como dije es la unica manera que se me ocurre. Un ejemplo facil seria, pedirle 5 numeros a un usuario y sacar el promedio de ellos. Yo lo haria haciendo 5 prompt() y guardarlos en 5 variables distintas, a eso voy, hay otra manera de hacer el procedimiento sin que tenga que usar objetos o arreglos?

Comment: Estoy en un curso de javascript, por lo que todavia no me interesa guardarlos en una base de datos ni hacer nada relevante con los datos que pido, solo son ejercicios para familiarizarse con el lenguaje, y me surgio la duda ya que poner 5 prompt() uno abajo del otro se me hizo raro.

Comment: Es mucho más simple con arreglos la verdad. Y si antes entiendes como funcionan mejor. Agrega el codigo que tienes hasta ahora a ver como vas

Comment: @Excorpion Ya publique el codigo, es un ejemplo sencillo de una operacion con 6 números pero espero se entienda la duda

Comment: Puedes guardar los datos donde tu quieres entonces, cual es el problema ??

Comment: No es problema, solo ver si podia ahorrar codigo, no repetir ese prompt() 6 veces

Comment: Puedes pedir el prompt dentro de un for, asi lo pedirías veces que quieras

Answer (score 0):

Podes crear las variables globales dinámicamente como propiedades del objeto global ( en este ejemplo es `window` )

```js
let myObj = this; // en este caso el global es window
let max = 6;
for (i = 1; max >= i; i++) {
  // una propiedad de un objeto se puede acceder con corchetes
  // "como si fuera un array"
  myObj[`num${i}`] = parseInt(
    prompt(`${i}/${max} Ingrese un numero entero`)
  );
}

let operacion = (num1 + num2 + num3) + ((num3 * num4 * num5) + num6);
let sOperacion = `(${num1} + ${num2} + ${num3}) + ((${num3} * ${num4} * ${num5}) + ${num6})`;

console.log(sOperacion, '=', operacion);
// diferentes formas de acceder a una variable global
console.log(
  "num1:",
  num1,
  window.num1,
  window['num1'],
  myObj.num1,
  myObj['num1']
)
console.log(
  "num2:",
  num2,
  window.num2,
  window['num2'],
  myObj.num2,
  myObj['num2']
)
```

Comment: Pero lo que el quiere es guardar los prompt en variables diferentes, no quiere realizar arreglos. Además, la suma no es correcta al final (no se porque) deberia ser 72 el resultado

Comment: son variables, las variables globales son propiedades del objeto global. la suma errónea debe ser por que lo considera string ahi lo reviso